# How preserve Entityframework SSDL changes?

Tags: entity-framework-4

How can I preserve SSDL changes? each time I open Entity framework model designer it overrides and remove my casacade delete attribute added to SSDL manually for many to many relations. I am using Entity framework 4.0 and model first approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That's a "feature" of the designer.

But the designer will recognize and support cascades if they're in your database. Are they?

Comment: Thanks. This would work fine when you are generating your model from the database. In our case we are using Model First approach and generating the database scripts from Entity framework designer. This means each time after generating the scripts we have to manually create cascades delete for many to many relations in the database.